# access Variables within function, which defines model to use it on test data Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am already very impressed with Tensorflow and it's automatic chain rule when it comes to find derivative. But I have one question, is it possible to access Variables from function which models train data?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np




X1 = np.array([[1,2,3]],dtype=np.float32).T #train features

X2 = np.array([[1.5,2.2]],dtype=np.float32).T #test features

y1 = np.array([[10,20,30]],dtype=np.float32).T #train label

y2 = np.array([[15,22]], dtype=np.float32).T #test features



x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,None])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,1])

def model(data):
    w0 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1,1]),dtype=tf.float32)
    b0 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1,1]),dtype=tf.float32)
    model = tf.add(tf.matmul(data,w0),b0)

    return model



result = model(X1)
loss = tf.square(result-y1)
train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(loss)


with tf.Session() as sess:
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)

    for i in range(1000):
        sess.run([train],feed_dict={x:X1,y:y1})


    print(sess.run(result))

# Would something like this be possible?:
# print(sess.run(model(X2))) test data ???
```

Session already holds some data regarding weights and bias. Is it possible to get it out by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible! The weights and bias would be re-used for the test data. You would ideally want to run,

```
sess.run(result, feed_dict={x: X2, y: y2})
```

Comment: I have tried this before asking here. The problem is, sess.run(result, feed_dict={x: X2, y: y2}) outputs values for X1.

Comment: Got it now, I had to change variable to placeholder in function model. Thanks